# python delete(key) couchbase causing time out

Tags: python, couchbase

I am deleting key from couchbase bucket. But it is causing time out but get(key) is working always.

```
default_connection=couchbase_service.get_default_connection()
default_connection.delete(key)
```

Exception

```
[Client-Side timeout exceeded for operation. Inspect network conditions or increase the timeout]
_TimeoutError_0x17 (generated, catch TimeoutError): <Key=u'foo', RC=0x17[Client-
Side timeout exceeded for operation. Inspect network conditions or increase the
timeout], Operational Error, Results=1, C Source=(src/multiresult.c,282)>
```

Comment: Could you share some environment details on the client and server side?  And the network?

Comment: Actually i was needed vpn to connect and i was not connected with vpn , thats why i got this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it exactly the same value of `key`?

Depending on your deployment, you may have some items on disk which take longer to retrieve and some in memory. The default timeout is 2.5s, which is quite long, but your disk could actually be quite slow.

I don't have enough info, but at the moment I'm guessing that may be the cause.

One tool to possibly see more info would be to [turn up logging](http://docs.couchbase.com/developer/c-2.4/logging.html).

Comment: Actually i was needed vpn to connect and i was not connected with vpn , thats why i got this issue. Thanks Matt. :)